# Scroll down not working using smoothscroll plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I need to make the scrolling smoothly,so i've used this [plugin](https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll)

Sadly,it broke my scroll down functionality.

I also use this function,for some extra option on plugin:

```
$(function () {
  $.srSmoothscroll({
    // defaults
    step: 55,
    speed: 400,
    ease: 'swing',
    target: $('body'),
    container: $(window)
  });
});
```

Does anyone know what is the problem? or should i look for another one?

**UPDATE** It works if i use this,but only in chrome:

```
$(function () {
  $.srSmoothscroll({
    // defaults
    step: 55,
    speed: 400,
    ease: 'swing',
    target: $('#container'),
    container: $('body')
  })
})
```

My page has a full width,height container id which is the target for this plugin,and its container is the body.

Comment: What are trying to do, could you please give me more details. Are trying to build a single page website? please provide a code example or screenshot

Comment: Try this code.
Did you add jquery mouse wheel script & jQuery?


  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.0.6/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
      $.srSmoothscroll()
    })
  </script>

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? I included mousewheel min js as it's a dependency of smoothscroll http://jsfiddle.net/JjPrU/851/

Comment: @MouhamadKawas , yes

Comment: @grdevphl , yes, how did you do that?

Comment: You'll need to include this in your project: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

Comment: Try this https://github.com/ChrisWojcik/single-page-nav
I use it in all my single page websites

Comment: @grdevphl , i copy paste the code from your fiddle,but the script is not working anymore,am i missing something?

Comment: Do you have it in a fiddle? Or are you seeing any errors in the dev console?

Comment: all of your suggestion worked,but only for up scroll,the down scroll is not working

Comment: @grdevphl , i have no errors in dev console. I think it's a plugin issue

Comment: check the update please

Comment: the fiddle I posted earlier works the same for me in chrome, firefox, and safari...not sure how to help